# ASP.NET MVC routing: 404 with more than one parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I got a pretty basic ASP.NET MVC (1) routing qeustion but I couldn't find an answer by now.

I want to call an action method which has three parameters but I'm running into an 404 when I call it with more than one parameter.

Route looks like this (I removed all other routes but the default one):

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Test",
   "{id}/{page}/{lineend}",
   new { controller = "Basic", action = "Test" },
   new { id = @"\d+", page = @"\d+" }
);
```

The method looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Test(int? id, int? page, string lineend)
{
    // some code here
    return new ViewResult();
}
```

This is what happens:

```
http://localhost:55462/Basic/Test/
```

works

```
http://localhost:55462/Basic/Test/1
```

works

```
http://localhost:55462/Basic/Test/1/2
```

gives a 404

```
http://localhost:55462/Basic/Test/1/2/3
```

gives a 404

Removing the constraints or changing the method signature to (int, int, string) has the same effect.
In the first and second case the application complains about a null parameter, the other cases lead to a 404.

I know this issue has to be pretty basic but I just don't get it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Test",
   "{id}/{page}/{*lineend}",
   new { controller = "Basic", action = "Test" },
   new { id = @"\d+", page = @"\d+" }
);
```

It is catch-all parameter. In action you have to split string using '/'

Answer (score 0):

I foud it out myself.
(And I hope it is correct that I add it as a separate answer.)

As expected the answer is quite simple.
With the routing configuration above you need to leave out the controller name in the URL so this works:

```
http://localhost:55462/Test/1/2/3
```